# adobe AIR app and bluetooth

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, bluetooth

I want to build a adobe Air application that sends an image to a mobile phone via bluetooth.
Do you know of a framework or library to do that directly or indirectly? I mean using only flex or do I have to use another language also, such as java?

any hints are welcome
thanks in advance 
thodoris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Thodoris.  You'll probably have to use merapi + a bluetooth api built on java.

I'm not sure if it is part of the community, but I heard recently that the framework has been ported to c#.

There are certainly other options as well.  For example, there is a way to deploy weborb with your AIR install.  Then, with the instance of a java or iis 'server' running client-side, you can invoke java or .net methods through a localhost "amfEndpoint".

I hope those couple of options help.  Best of luck.  --jeremy

Comment: I just re-read my post and thought, "there has to be an example of the client weborb deployment."  Found this: http://www.themidnightcoders.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=2622