# is there a way to access bluetooth on android via adobe air

Tags: android, air, bluetooth

Can you access the bluetooth API of android via adobe air for mobile?

Comment: similar previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098114/adobe-air-app-and-bluetooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Adobe AIR developer, but from what I know it is runtime for developing rich Internet applications that should run out of browser on your target device. So by default shouldn't be interested in accessing platform dependent resources and APIs. Even so, there is a possibility called [native process API](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/features/) and here there is an [example article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html), probably if you digg you'll find more information about it.

> Create native installers allowing you to launch and communicate with native processes using standard input and output. Using the native process API, communicate with native libraries built using Java™ and .NET and native applications such as grep for file searching. You can also create operating system–specific installers (native installers). Applications that use the native process API must be deployed using a native installer.

Second step it would be for you document yourself, about the Bluetooth API of Android. They use BlueZ, so you could use the C API, or if your needs are not soffisticated you could use the Java API.

The actual response is yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a Native Process API:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/invoke-native-process-in-adobe-air-2/

however, unfortunately, it doesn't look like it will allow you to do want you want.