# sharing data b/w mobile devices in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, communication, data-sharing

I wanted to know what options are there for sharing data b/w mobile devices in Flex.
I want to share data stored in one device in Sqlite database.

Can I share data using Bluetooth or some other device to device transfer technology ? How will this can be done ?

Or this is only possible through internet with intermediary server b/w communicating devices ?
Also how can this be done ?

Devices can be android (mobile/tablet) or iOS (iPhone/iPad).

Comment: Normally I'd recommend putting the device on a server.  If two AIR apps [even mobile] are connected to the same Wifi network I believe you can use a LocalConnection.  If the two devices are connected via bluetooth; it is possible a LocalConnection may work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 1. I think you can go with UDP if you are on a wifi. 2. I've worked with UPnP before, you can use it(It is based on UDP), but it will  complicate things for you as there is no library available for air to perform UPnP. 3. Use of NFC, adobe air 3 supports NFC between mobiles, bt the mobile should have this capability. 4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098114/adobe-air-app-and-bluetooth

Comment: I'd say the easiest way is to use a server. Also you I guess you could take a look at native extension for Wifi or Bluetooth communications between devices.